# git merging two branches interchangeably

Tags: git

Suppose I have a two branches master and develop. What will be the difference between these two merges:-

```
git checkout master
git merge develop
```

and

```
git checkout develop
git merge master
```

Comment: Try `git diff -p master..develop`. I would the response to be empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have the following commit graph:

```
master +--P-----+------+
           \
            \
development  +----+-----+-----+
```

The first command will result in:

```
master +--P-----+------+---------R1
           \                    /
            \                  /
development  +----+-----+-----+
```

The second command into:

```
master +--P-----+------+-----------
           \                       \
            \                       \
development  +----+-----+-----+------R2
```

The difference is thus that the result of the merge will be placed on a different branch.

But `R1` and `R2` will have the same state of files since a merge means both differences from `P` are applied if and only if no conflicts occur.

Furthermore you can alter the *merge strategy* with `ours`, `theirs`,... to favor the difference of the current or the other branch. So:

```
git merge -s theirs development #first version
```

is the same as:

```
git merge -s ours master #second version
```

Finally, if case a *merge-conflict* occurs, this will of course result in the opposite conflict file. (Because the conflict file places the current branch first).